# Jquery mobile - não carrega meu main.js depois do change page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Montei uma página utilizando jquery mobile com a função de todos os botões num arquivo main.js
Divs que quando clicadas eu verifico no js e faço a ação ex:

```
$( "#mais-op" ).on( "tap", function() {
  $.mobile.changePage( "2.html", { transition: "pop"} );
});
```

Tudo funciona normal até eu fazer o change page pra outra página. Quando to na outra pagina o on tap não rola
como se não tivesse carregado mais o main.js. Porém se eu der reload na pagina tudo volta a funcionar

Como resolvo isso?
Obrigado

Comment: Este método changePage puxa uma página para dentro da página atual? Se sim o método faz reload dos componentes jquery?

Comment: Ela chama uma pagina externa e carrega ela.
Se tiver um alert por exemplo dentro do delegate pagecreate que verifica se a pagina 2.html foi carregada ele funciona. Mas nada mais funciona (evento de click, tap) só quando recarrega a página

Comment: Desculpem, foi bobeira
eu estava usando ids em alguns elementos ao invés da forma correta que é utilizar classes. Então como é carregado tudo na mesma página, um elemento com o mesmo id em outra página não funciona, porém nenhum erro é gerado no console. Dai eu não conseguia saber qual quera o problema. 
Só depois que descobri a besteira que estava fazendo.
De qualquer forma obrigado